# fio: how to write 2X user capacity?

Tags: linux, benchmark, fio

My system has SSDs and I wanted to run some benchmark tests on it based on SSS PTS (SNIA). For example, for IOPS test, the spec suggested to use QD=32, TC=4 and for doing IO, the spec says following.

```
Run SEQ Workload Independent Pre-conditioning - Write 2X User Capacity with 128KiB SEQ writes, writing the entire ActiveRange without LBA restrictions.
```

My system has an SSD of size 12 TB, so I planned to invoke fio two times in sequence as below.

```
fio  --iodepth=32 --bs=128 --numjobs=4 --rw=write --size=3T ...  # write 4*3T=12T
fio  --iodepth=32 --bs=128 --numjobs=4 --rw=write --size=3T ...  # write 4*3T=12T
```

But, from the first command only, I got `fio: native_fallocate call failed: No space left on device`. I think this is expected since, there are some other small files/dirs such as "lost+found". I think, I am doing something wrong here and there must be a better right way of doing this. Can somebody suggest me how should I parameterized my fio command so that it writes 2X user capacity as suggested in PTS spec? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to access all the space of the SSD as you have a filesystem atop it which may in turn has restrictions on the space available for files. You will need to look at the actual space available via something like `df` and work with that number (and even some of that may be unavailable so you may need to use something lower).

If you don't actually need four jobs you might be able to get away with making a single file via [`fill_fs=1`](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_man.html#cmdoption-arg-loops) and then you can use [`loops=2`](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_man.html#cmdoption-arg-loops)...

**Caution**: It follows that running your main filesystem (that is used for logs etc) out of space is bad for the health of your system...